# How to match a string column with a corresponding number column showing the stringvalue in Excel 2007?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

How do I match a string column with a corresponding number column showing the string in Excel 2007?

For example:

```
Col A       Col B
Mr X        50
Mr Y        100
Mr Z        150
```

"Show the person who has Max value from Col B". I want Mr Z to show up in my cell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd transpose the columns and use `VLOOKUP`.

```
Col A    Col B  
50       Mr X
100      Mr Y   
150      Mr Z



VLOOKUP(Max(A:A),A:B,2,FALSE)
```

This assumes unique values in Col A, though.